# Avoid error blocked:mixed-content request error

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working with angular 8 and node js (express), i am doing a request but i am getting the error  blocked:mixed-content because the frontet is https but the backend is in another server and is http and i can't change it to https.

There is a way to avoid this error without change the bakend from http to https.

i am doing the request like this:

`return this.http.post(this.host + 'login', data);`

Comment: You probably just need a CORS policy on the server.  I don't speak Node so I can't help, but http://x and https:/x are considered different domains and so your request will be blocked by default.